# Life cycle of Attachment Servlet

Tags: javascript, multithreading, servlets, jakarta-ee, thread-safety

I have a servlet which has a function readOpportunity. In readOpportunity, I have 3 readLine() statements. During my first request to the servlet this function works fine. But, if I am doing more than one request, the 3rd readLine statement i.e  bytesRead = in.readLine(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE) does not give the correct value.I got to know when I debugged the whole program step by step. I will appreciate if anyone can help me on this.

```
private String readOpportunity(ServletInputStream in, String boundary, Logger logger) throws MultipartUploadException, IOException {

    logger.finer("Reading opportunity number");

    // Check for content disposition

    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytesRead = in.readLine(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
    String line = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

    if (!line.startsWith("Content-Disposition: form-data"))
        throw new MultipartUploadException("Missing or invalid content-disposition");

    // Get the opportunuity number

    if (line.indexOf("name=\"opportunity\"") == -1)
        throw new MultipartUploadException("Missing opportunity number");

    // Skip the blank seperator line

    bytesRead = in.readLine(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (bytesRead != 2)
        throw new MultipartUploadException("Missing seperator line");

    **bytesRead = in.readLine(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);**
    String opportunity = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    if (opportunity.length() < 3)
        throw new MultipartUploadException("Missing opportunity number");

    // Read ending boundary

    bytesRead = in.readLine(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
    line = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

    if (!line.startsWith(boundary))
        throw new MultipartUploadException("Missing or invalid ending boundary");

    // Remove trailing new line

    opportunity = opportunity.substring(0, opportunity.length() - 2);
    return opportunity;
}
```

I have marked the statement where I am getting deviated results on more than one request to servlet. Since, the bytesRead is giving a different result so the Opportunity is read properly.

Comment: What about the encoding of the data?? `new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead)` uses the platform's default enconding... how is your http client encoding  the data been transferred (utf-8, ANSI) and how do you expect such data ??

Comment: My encoding is UTF-8

Comment: On every more than one request to this method , the marked readLine statement doesnot produce the desired output. Innother words, the marked bytesRead doesnot calculate correctly

Comment: Do you have instance attributes on your servlet (generally, Servlets instances are pooled between threads, may be something is been cached) ?? Can you post your servlet complete code ?

Comment: Actually, I got to know that my error was in the javascript file to which it was linked to. I appreciate your helping hand. Do you guys know how to make a text field in smartclient javascript non editable.